# Strong reference cycle not performing as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a class called Item that has two pointers to Item, *containedItem and *container.  I declare them as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic) Item *containedItem
@property (nonatomic) Item *container
```

I override dealloc within Item as follows:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Destroyed: %@",self);
}
```

so that I may see which items are being destroyed.  I create two items and make it so that one points to the other  as its container and the other points to the first as its contained.  As the default attribute is being a strong pointer, I would think this would lead to a memory leak.  However, when I run my program, it shows that both Items are destroyed.  I am wondering how the Items can be destroyed when both have a strong pointer to them (from the other).

Comment: Can you show more details ? I didn't understand

Comment: Are you sure you haven't omitted anything important? If I run this code https://gist.github.com/bartekchlebek/d2bdde073551c536f5b1 dealloc is not called, as expected.

Comment: Perhaps you are not compiling your code with ARC enabled? If that's the case, the default for property is not `strong` but `assign`